# When clicking on “home” page from any other page, it goes to IP address and my website doesn’t load

Tags: homepage, wp-config, site-url

I recently set up my WordPress website and just noticed that if I click the `home` page from any other page, it points to the IP of my instance and the website won’t load. I have checked the URL(s) from the admin panel <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>General</kbd>. They are correctly configured but currently grayed out. Is the only solution to this is to edit the `wp-config.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs are greyed out in the Settings page because of the entries in the `wp-config.php` file. If there are entries for these values, those values override the values in the `wp-options` table, and the override makes the Settings values uneditable.

See this in the Codex: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

> It is possible to set the site URL manually in the `wp-config.php` file.
>
> Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where `example.com` is the correct location of your site.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
> define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
> ```
>
> **This is not necessarily the best fix, it’s just hard-coding the values into the site itself. You won’t be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.**

(Emphasis added)

That's why I am not a big fan of making URL changes in the `wp-config.php` file. I think it is better (and more proper) to change those values in the `wp-options` table. (IMHO).

Look at your `wp-config.php` for those two 'defines'. I'd bet that you would find values there. I think that it is better to put those URLs in the `wp-options` table. Again, IMHO.